# Optional TSql Clause dependent on a match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is trying to determine who is in a user's network and I am having some trouble getting it to work when the user has multiple referrals with different companies.  Here is my current query:

```
DECLARE @CompanyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '95dd17d8-7bc6-4fcf-871b-de8f3ac52404'
DECLARE @UserID INT = 123

SELECT u.NAME,
       u.Email,
       u.AppID,
       u.PhotoUrl       AS [Image],
       Cast(CASE
              WHEN Count(m.MeetingID) > 0
                    OR a.CompanyID = @CompanyID THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END AS BIT) AS IsReferrable
FROM   Users u
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT ReferredUserEmail,
                          Max(CompanyID) AS CompanyID
                   FROM   Referral r
                   WHERE  ReferringUserID = @UserID
                   GROUP  BY ReferredUserEmail) AS a
               ON u.Email = a.ReferredUserEmail
       LEFT JOIN Meeting m
              ON u.ID = m.UserID
                 AND m.CompanyID = @CompanyID
GROUP  BY u.NAME,
          u.Email,
          u.AppID,
          u.PhotoUrl,
          a.CompanyID
```

My issue arises in the sub select where I have to use an aggregate on CompanyID.  I was hoping to avoid making this whole query part of another sub select to remove the duplicate users I get when I remove the group by in my first sub select.  I am not sure the best way to make sure I don't have duplicate users in my final select, but account for users being in the Referral table with multiple CompanyIDs.  I was thinking I could add the where clause in my sub select to look for tha CompanyID again, but then I lose out on users that are related to the searched on user but not the company involved.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: from what I can see here a right join will end up giving you some rows in the resultset with NULL in all columns apart from the IsReferrable column, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand a bit from your explanation, and your database schema and business task aren't obvious, either. But from what I was able to devise, it might help to rewrite all this into a `UNION ALL` - taking users related to referrals and users related to meetings separately from each other, and then unionise these two resultsets.

```
select ..., 0 as [ResultType]
from Referral r
    inner join Users u on u.Email = r.ReferredUserEmail
where r.ReferringUserID = @UserID
union all
select ..., 1 as [ResultType]
from Meeting m
    inner join Users u ON u.ID = m.UserID
where m.CompanyID = @CompanyID
```

You can then wrap all this up into a sub-query and select only part of the rows, depending on what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, converting the `JOIN` to an `EXISTS` in the `CASE` statement (note the CASE statement is shortcircuited so put the most likely option first):

```
DECLARE @CompanyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '95dd17d8-7bc6-4fcf-871b-de8f3ac52404'
DECLARE @UserID INT = 123

SELECT DISTINCT 
       u.NAME,
       u.Email,
       u.AppID,
       u.PhotoUrl       AS [Image],
       Cast(CASE
              WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM Meeting m 
                    WHERE m.UserId = u.Id AND m.ComapnyId = @CompanyId) > 0 THEN 0
              WHEN EXISTS (
                      SELECT * 
                      FROM Referral r 
                      WHERE r.ReferringUserId = @UserId AND
                            r.CompanyId = @CompanyId AND
                            r.ReferredUserEmail = u.Email) THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END AS BIT) AS IsReferrable
FROM   Users u
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish but here's a try.

First, the right join seems kind of unneeded. If there are referrals to non existing users, you would end up with a row with name, email etc as null and a 0 or 1 as IsReferrable. I'm going to assumes this is not wanted.

Also, this code is completed untested and could very well contain syntax errors.

```
with referredusers as ( -- Get referred users and first check for IsReferrable if any referral contains the company id
  select ReferredUserEmail as Email, case when sum(case when CompanyId = @CompanyId then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as IsReferrable
  from Referral
  group by ReferredUserEmail
)
select u.NAME, u.Email, u.AppID, u.PhotoUrl
  , case
    when r.IsReferrable = 1 then 1
    when exists (select * from Meeting m where m.UserID = u.ID and m.CompanyID = @CompanyId) then 1 -- By using sub select, group by on user is not needed
    else 0
  end as IsReferrable
from referredusers r
  inner join Users u on u.Email = r.Email;
```

Comment: Right join definitely needed, userid is a foreign key.  Also too much pseudo code, if im reading it right it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @DanJ I don't see any pseudo code here, have you tried it?